# How to add optional column in JDBI?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbi

I have big SQL, about 50 lines, and we use JDBI with Postgresql, and I need to add one additional not mandatory column, so I did:

```
,case when :byPortfolio is true then ia1.investmentAccountAbbreviationCode else null end as portfolio
```

so if :byPortfolio is true this column should be removed, and if false this column should be present. Also ia1.investmentAccountAbbreviationCode should be present in Group by clause if it's present, so I added:

```
,case when :byPortfolio2 is true then ia1.investmentAccountAbbreviationCode else null end
```

and it works if I fun it as SQL query, then I copied it to sql.stg template file for JDBI and now when I run it I see an exceptioin:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "ia1.investmentaccountabbreviationcode" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

I don't understand why JDBI can't handle it. Function described like this:

```
@SqlQuery
@UseStringTemplateSqlLocator
@RegisterBeanMapper(SolutionOwnershipDataEntity.class)
List<SolutionOwnershipDataEntity> getSolutionOwnershipPercentageOfFundByDate(
        @Bind("inputDate") String inputDate,
        @Bind("fundSeriesId") Integer fundSeriesId,
        @Bind("governanceCommitteeTypeCode") String governanceCommitteeTypeCode,
        @Bind("byPortfolio") boolean byPortfolio,
        @Bind("assetClass") String assetClass,
        @Bind("vehicleType") String vehicleType);
```

Please help to fix it? We can fix current code or maybe there is other way to handle unnecessary column? I mean I can write two 50 lines SQL with same code, only difference would be presence or absence of one column, but I want to have one query with one unnecessary column, what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

For `byPortfolio`, you need to use `@Define` instead of `@Bind`.
`@Bind` is only for binding values to parameters of a query, while `@Define` can be used for placeholders and templating.

For the templating, you can then put the optional parts between `<if(byPortfolio)>` and `<endif>`. The template syntax is not related to normal SQL.

Here is a complete example from the documentation:

```
@SqlQuery("""
  select id, name
  from account
  order by <if(sort)> <sortBy>, <endif> id
  """)
@UseStringTemplateEngine
List<Account> selectAll(@Define boolean sort, @Define String sortBy);
```

For more details, please have look at the official documentation: https://jdbi.org/#_stringtemplate_4